# SSIS Process Task for Powershell script making SOAP call

Tags: xml, powershell, soap, ssis

After long hours of research into the problem, I've run into a bit of a wall. Essentially I am attempting to make a SOAP call to an exposed web service (which I have the WSDL for). I am able to run my PowerShell script to make the call and returns the XML result. I am having trouble getting this connected into SSIS and passing that XML to be parsed. I've read articles explaining doing it through the webservice (which I get an error message on webmethod) and script/process task.

Currently working with process task that calls a PowerShell script to make the SOAP call and retrieve the XML response which I can parse and insert into a SQL table

Process/webservice/script task
VB code (not proficient in)
PowerShell to save the response to a file and insert into SQL

```
#setting TLS to 1.2 as webservice rejects 1.0
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 
[System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

#setting URL Endpoint
$uri = "WebserviceURL"

#structuring the request with the infile being the soap action with headers
$post = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -InFile c:\SOAPREQUESTACTION -ContentType "text/xml" -method post`
```

Expected results - SSIS able to parse XML response into variables and insert into SQL table, after which it will update items as the attributes change on next SOAP call

example response

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><env:Envelope 
xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Body> 
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="WEBSERVICEURN">
<wd:Report_Entry>
<wd:Preferred_Name_-_First_Name>Joe</wd:Preferred_Name_-_First_Name>
<wd:Preferred_Name_-_Last_Name>Professional</wd:Preferred_Name_- 
_Last_Name>
<wd:businessTitle>Joe Professional Title</wd:businessTitle>
<wd:Department wd:Descriptor="Joes Professional Department">
</wd:Report_Entry></wd:Report_Data></env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

Comment: Have you tried just using `New-WebServiceProxy`

Comment: i have, powershell sciprt works, more so concerned with using in SSIS. I was able to get the response to a variable but unsure of how to call and parse the variable once used in SSIS

Comment: Paste the XML response into your question. I can tell you how to handle that string

Comment: @KeithL the OP added the XML response check it out

Answer (score 1):

First of all I had to clean up your XML to:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Body> 
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="WEBSERVICEURN">
<wd:Report_Entry>
<wd:Preferred_Name_-_First_Name>Joe</wd:Preferred_Name_-_First_Name>
<wd:Preferred_Name_-_Last_Name>Professional</wd:Preferred_Name_-_Last_Name>
<wd:businessTitle>Joe Professional Title</wd:businessTitle>
<wd:Department wd:Descriptor="Joes Professional Department"/>
</wd:Report_Entry></wd:Report_Data></env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

I assume that it is downloaded into a file. I called this file xml.txt

1. Add a dataflow
2. In dataflow add a script component (source)
3. Add your columns to output
4. Edit script
5. Add to namespaces
6. using System.Xml.Serialization;
7. using System.Collections.Generic;
8. add the following code to CreateOutputRows()

   ```
   var xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\temp\xml.txt");
   System.IO.Stream s_xml = new System.IO.MemoryStream(xml);

   XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
   var results = (Envelope)serializer.Deserialize(s_xml);
   foreach (var entry in results.Body.Report_Data.Report_Entry)
   {
       Output0Buffer.AddRow();
       Output0Buffer.fname = entry.Preferred_Name__First_Name;
       Output0Buffer.lname = entry.Preferred_Name__Last_Name;
       Output0Buffer.title = entry.BusinessTitle;
       Output0Buffer.dept = entry.Department.Descriptor;
   }
   s_xml.Close();
   ```
9. Use a website like xml2csharp.com to convert xml to classes and paste the classes below:

   ```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Department", Namespace = "WEBSERVICEURN")]
    public class Department
    {
         [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Descriptor", Namespace = "WEBSERVICEURN")]
         public string Descriptor { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Report_Entry", Namespace = "WEBSERVICEURN")]
    public class Report_Entry
    {
         [XmlElement(ElementName = "Preferred_Name_-_First_Name", Namespace = "WEBSERVICEURN")]
         public string Preferred_Name__First_Name { get; set; }
         [XmlElement(ElementName = "Preferred_Name_-_Last_Name", Namespace = "WEBSERVICEURN")]
         public string Preferred_Name__Last_Name { get; set; }
         [XmlElement(ElementName = "businessTitle", Namespace = "WEBSERVICEURN")]
         public string BusinessTitle { get; set; }
         [XmlElement(ElementName = "Department", Namespace = "WEBSERVICEURN")]
         public Department Department { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Report_Data", Namespace = "WEBSERVICEURN")]
    public class Report_Data
    {
          [XmlElement(ElementName = "Report_Entry", Namespace = "WEBSERVICEURN")]
          public List<Report_Entry> Report_Entry { get; set; }
          [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "wd", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
          public string Wd { get; set; }
     }

     [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
     public class Body
     {
          [XmlElement(ElementName = "Report_Data", Namespace = "WEBSERVICEURN")]
          public Report_Data Report_Data { get; set; }
     }

     [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
     public class Envelope
     {
           [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
           public Body Body { get; set; }
           [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "env", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
           public string Env { get; set; }
     }
   ```
10. Save and exit
11. You now have your columns in the data flow to do whatever you want with.